# Dealing with correlated covariates

Tags: correlation, multicollinearity, predictor

I am assessing pairwise association between covariates.  I have used the chi-square test to determine association between categorical covariates, pearson's correlation coefficient between numeric variables and a one way ANOVA test to determine correlation between numeric variables and categoric variables.

I wanted to find clusters of covariates that were associated and choose one.  My problem is that I just ended up with one cluster, but I did want to include more than one covariate.

e.g. gender was associated with weight and smoking status.  Age was associated with currently ill and smoking status.

Comment: correlated covariates is usually discussed under the tag [tag:multicollinearity] , you could add that! (and look through the many posts ...) Otherwise, this question lacks contexts and so there is little we can say ... please add more details

Answer (score 1):

covariates are almost always correlated. if you do experimental research then it's not a problem at all. in observational studies if they're highly correlated you may run into some issues, of course. in this case you can try PCA, so that if you get PC1 it will represent all the variables in the cluster, which may alleviate your concern about using only one variable.